# run oozie shell script

Tags: shell, apache-spark, oozie

i want to run a shell script that contains `spark-submit` and i kerberos installed. this is my file:

```
#!/bin/sh
kinit -kt zeri.keytab zeri@GT.COM
spark-submit --class structure_Ot  --master yarn://xx.xx.xx.50  /home/spark_jars/ot_spark_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /user/zeri/worskspace/ hdfs:///user/zeri/file/app_desc hdfs:///user/zeri/file/rat_desc ot_appsession ot_appsession_agg  hdfs:///user/zeri/filter
```

my `spark-submit` work fine but when i try to make a workflow with oozie using that file i got an error.

And i was trying to run spark jar with oozie and i got an error too here is my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591309/run-spark-jar-with-oozie?noredirect=1#comment78142171_45591309).

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376108/spark-1-6-token-can-be-issued-only-with-kerberos-or-web-authentication ?

Comment: Didi you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506060/oozie-spark-action-error-main-class-org-apache-oozie-action-hadoop-sparkmain ?